# Multiple annotation validation check sequence

Tags: java, validation, hibernate-validator

What is the sequence of validating via multiple annotations?

```
   @NotBlank(message = "Shouldn't be blank or contain whitespaces")
   @UserNameUnique(message = "Creating user requires unique userName")
   private String userName;
```

As you see I have custom annotation. It looks like even `@NotBlank` fail `@UserNameUnique` is still triggered redundantly so I need do `notNull` check in it. I know that I can transfer whole logic to my custom validator but I'm curious about mechanism of triggering multiple annotation during validation process.

Edit: 
Additionally when I run mockMvc tests, validator is chosen randomly and different messages are printed so it complicating things even more :)

Answer (score 2):

As you say, either you roll all into a custom constraints. Alternatively you can make use of a group sequence. Check the documentation for this feature.